# How can i update the ids field with this rethinkdb document structure?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-ruby

Having trouble trying to update the ids field in the document structure:

```
[
    [0] {
                   "rank" => nil,
             "profile_id" => 3,
        "daily_providers" => [
            [0] {
                "relationships" => [
                  [0] {
                      "relationship_type" => "friend",
                                  "count" => 0
                  },
                  [1] {
                      "relationship_type" => "acquaintance",
                                    "ids" => [],
                                  "count" => 0
                  }
                ],
                "countries" => [
                   [0] {
                         "country_name" => "United States",
                         "count" => 0
                       },

                   [1] {
                         "country_name" => "Great Britain",
                         "count" => 0
                       }
                ],
                "provider_name" => "foo",
                 "date" => 20130912
            },
            [1] {
                "provider_name" => "bar"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you can do

```
r.db('test').table('test').get(3).update(function(doc) {
  return {daily_providers: doc("daily_providers").changeAt(
    0,
    doc("daily_providers").nth(0).merge({
      relationships: doc("daily_providers").nth(0)("relationships").changeAt(
        1,
        doc("daily_providers").nth(0)("relationships").nth(1).merge({
          ids: [1]
        })
      )
    })
  )}
})
```

Which becomes in Ruby

```
r.db('test').table('test').get(3).update{ |doc|
  {"daily_providers" => doc["daily_providers"].changeAt(
    0,
    doc["daily_providers"][0].merge({
      "relationships" => doc["daily_providers"][0]["relationships"].changeAt(
        1,
        doc["daily_providers"][0]["relationships"][1].merge({
          ids => [1]
        })
      )
    })
  )}
}
```

You should probably have another table for the daily providers and do joins.
That would make things way more simpler.

Comment: I read a little too fast, I thought the dataset was the same as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763866/how-would-you-use-map-reduce-on-this-document-structuret -- updating...

Comment: That also requires that I need to know the index number of the embedded array?

Comment: Yes, how else can you know which daily_provider or relationship you want to update?

Comment: Might not be ideal for documents that change in time. Index numbers may differ from document to document. Knowing the index number might be impossible, without having to parse through the document first